# Сворачивание программы в трей

Tags: c#, wpf

Как реализовать сворачивание программы в трей?

Comment: Есть ответ на английской версии SO: [Minimize app to system tray](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7625421)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Добавьте в проект ссылки на сборки System.Windows.Forms и System.Drawing.

```
public partial class Window1 : System.Windows.Window
{

    public Window1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        System.Windows.Forms.NotifyIcon ni = new System.Windows.Forms.NotifyIcon();
        ni.Icon = new System.Drawing.Icon("Main.ico");
        ni.Visible = true;
        ni.DoubleClick += 
            delegate(object sender, EventArgs args)
            {
                this.Show();
                this.WindowState = WindowState.Normal;
            };
    }

    protected override void OnStateChanged(EventArgs e)
    {
        if (WindowState == System.Windows.WindowState.Minimized)
            this.Hide();

        base.OnStateChanged(e);
    }
}
```

[Взято из ответа с английского SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10230672/6641468)