# Как свернуть окно в трей?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Казалось бы банальный вопрос, но гугл показывает лишь решения для WinForm..

Собственно по сабжу: нужно чтобы при нажатии на кнопку сворачивания или закрытия приложение сворачивалось в трей.

Я понимаю, что можно отловить событие сворачивания и закрытия и вместо них скрыть форму. А вот что дальше: как поместить функциональную иконку в трей?

Иконка с вполне привычным для неё функционалом вроде раскрытия окна по двойному клику и наличием контекстного меню.

Как такое реализовать? Желательно с соблюдением паттерна MVVM.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/651608/%D0%A1%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D1%8B-%D0%B2-%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B9/651617#651617

Comment: @Mr. Modest ваша неспособность найти ответы на свои вопросы на киберфоруме не дает вам право характеризовать тамошних ТС-ов подобным образом.

Comment: @Ev_Hyper извиняюсь, убрал оффтоп..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Я использовал это http://www.hardcodet.net/

```
xmlns:tb="http://www.hardcodet.net/taskbar"
....            
<tb:TaskbarIcon Grid.Row="0" DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource Locator}, Path=WindowControls}"
                Visibility="{Binding TaskbarVisibility}"
                ToolTipText="Программа в работе. Кликните, чтобы открыть окно"
                IconSource="mainIcon.ico"
                MenuActivation="RightClick"
                LeftClickCommand="{Binding ExpandWindowCommand}" />
```

Как видите, всё вполне в `MVVM`

Скачивается через `NUGET` этой командой:

`Install-Package Hardcodet.NotifyIcon.Wpf`

Comment: есть принципиальная разница в том, куда его размещать в окне?

Comment: Нет, он же не визуальный компонент.

Comment: даю в качестве иконки вектор xaml - в итоге иконки нет.. даю путь до ico файда - выскакивает ошибка, что не может найти файл (причём до компиляции xaml не ругается на отсутствие файла по заданному пути) =/

Comment: Иконка в ресурсах должна лежать

Comment: xaml у меня в StaticResource..

Comment: Только ico, насколько я знаю.

Comment: `IconSource="{Binding Mode=OneWay, Source={StaticResource PlusCircleIcon}}"` что-то вроде такого даю.. иконки не видно, но подсказка при наведении и контекстное меню работает =/

Comment: а как ico подключить в ресурсы? он у меня в папке Resources/Images/ico/icon.ico лежит

Comment: добавил в ресурсы `<Image Source="/ShikiDesk;component/Resources/Images/shiki.ico" x:Key="TrayIcon"/>` однако иконка по прежнему прозрачная.. то есть функционал есть, но её саму не видно

Comment: подключал вот так: `IconSource="{Binding Mode=OneWay, Source={StaticResource TrayIcon}}"`

Comment: Да зачем там биндинг, просто имя иконки которую вы закидываете в корень проекта в обозревателе. Всё. В конце концов почитайте на сайте компонента. Это работает у меня, железно.

Comment: так у меня сам файл окна не в корне лежит, поэтому путь вроде того, что я выше написал.. я пытался прямо этот путь задавать в IconSource и он выдавал ошибку, что не может найти =/ на сайте я тоже смотрю, и там указан относительный путь, который у меня почему то возвращает ошибку =/

Comment: http://pastexen.com/i/eLpglh4jkD.png - вот такая ошибка выходит

Comment: извините за беспокойство.. глупая невнимательность.. забыл включил ico файл в проект =_=

Comment: Возникла такая проблема: после закрытия приложения, иконка из трея не исчезает сама, пока я не наведу на неё мышью. В итоге. если я несколько раз открою и закрою приложение, в трее будет куча дубликатов. Они, конечно, исчезают после наведения на них мышью, но всё равно картина какая то не приятная.. Вот скрин: http://pastexen.com/i/Wf4tVEPsgP.png

Comment: Ну, у меня такой проблемы не было с ЭТИМ компонентом. Надо смотреть как вы там все реализовали. Наверно перед закрытием иконку стоит скрыть.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/3h7GCmdn - xaml
https://pastebin.com/ygT9vNEn - xaml.cs
Это в главном окне.

Comment: Mvvm фреймворк используете какой-нибудь?

Comment: паттерн использую, но фреймворки не юзаю.. кстати, скрытие иконки перед закртием не помогает.... пробовал Visible = Collapsed, всё равно не исчезает =/

Comment: Нет у вас mvvm - всё выполняется в `code-behind`

Comment: конкретно тут нет. Это сделано для упрощения.. на время теста

Comment: Странно, воссоздал - все нормально исчезает при закрытии приложения

Comment: попробую как-нибудь на других компьютерах тогда.. может это беда моего ноута? хотя всё равно странно =/